# Python Training and Testing Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, anaconda, training-data

While I am trying to run the last bit of the following code, I get an error I am not able to figure out why.

```
import random
combined_list = h_sub_text + s_sub_text
print(len(combined_list))
random.shuffle(combined_list)

training_part = int(len(combined_list) * .7)
print(len(combined_list))
training_set = combined_list[:training_part]
test_set =  combined_list[training_part:]
print (len(train_set))
print (len(test_set))

import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)

accuracy = nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, test_set)

print("Accuracy is: ", accuracy * 100)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-151936e75238> in <module>()
  2 from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier

----> 4 classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\naivebayes.py in train(cls, labeled_featuresets, estimator)

--> 194         for featureset, label in labeled_featuresets:
195             label_freqdist[label] += 1
196             for fname, fval in featureset.items():

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace `train_set` with `training_set`? `train_set` is not defined anywhere in the code that you give.

Comment: Sorry, its "NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)" . In the error it shows the right object.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is the value of *train_set* passed into *NaiveBayesClassifier.train()*. To really know we'd to know how that looks.
Whatever it is causes the "nltk" module to have the error.

From the NLTK source code at http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html:

> ```
> @classmethod
> def train(cls, labeled_featuresets, estimator=ELEProbDist):
>    """
>    :param labeled_featuresets: A list of classified featuresets,
>        i.e., a list of tuples ``(featureset, label)``.
> ```

The parameter for train() is a list of tuples. So given the error you have of trying to unpack too many values when only 2 are expected, that's not what you're passing in. Either a plain array or an array of arrays larger than 2.

Comment: Maybe NLTK method is not suitable for this. How can I apply sklearn-train-test-split in the code?

Comment: I'm not familiar with NLTK. First thing you can print out training_set to see what's being passed in. Also read the docs to understand what that's supposed to be.